# Entity Framework Core - load child entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

I'm using EF Core and have a problem with lazy loading.

My model is:

```
public class Product
{
  public int Id{get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public virtual Category Category {get; set;}
}

public class Category
{
  public int Id{get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Code to fetch products:

```
List<int> selectedCategories = new List<int> { 1, 2 };

// DatabaseContext inherited from DbContext
// Products is of type DbSet<Product>
IQueryable<Product> query = _dbContext.Products.Include(p=>p.Category);
IQueryable<Product> filtered = query.Where(p => selectedCategories.Contains(p.Category.Id));
var result = filtered.ToList();
```

The problem is: `filtered` list contains really filtered by category ids products but Category is null for all products. So when I pass this result to view and trying to get Category name I have a null reference exception.

How could I load Category entity with Product?

**UPD: Already resolved!**

I realized that I was using wrong `.Include` method from `System.Data.Entity` instead of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.

So if you faced the same problem check if you are using correct extension method from `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.

Comment: Ah I see you already solved your issue. Please post a proper "answer" by using the answer button, that way every reader can clearly see that this issue is solved.

Comment: Your issue cannot be resolved without fixing the  class  since your EF has the errors

Answer (score 2):

I realized that I was using wrong `.Include` method from `System.Data.Entity` instead of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.

So if you faced the same problem check if you are using correct extension method from `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.

Comment: It will be working as a bad example in a computer memory but you can't save it to DB

Comment: Product shoud have a foreign key CategoryId to provide a link between two classes.

Comment: @Sergey As you can see I was using wrong Include method. I've tried to add CategoryId and it doesn't help. Also I should say that saving object to DB is not related to this post. So, you are right, that I need CategoryId if I want to save this model, but it is not a solution of  the described problem.

Comment: Even if your solution  is for the learning and will not be working in a real EF context this is not the best solution.  You don't need two querie. One query is enough.

Comment: @Sergey As I said, it is just an example created for clearly understanding. Real model and filtering as much more complex.

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing EF6 and EF Core in one and the same project. Thus when working with EF Core there shouldn't be `System.Data.Entity` namespace at all.

Comment: @IvanStoev you are right. It was added due to inattention.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
var  filtered = _dbContext.Products
    .Include(p => p.Category) // maybe you don't need this
    .Where(p => selectedCategories.Contains(p.CategoryId))
    .ToList();
```

But your Product has an error. It should have a foreign  key CategoryId to provide a link between two classes.

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Nope, it should not. Any way it is just an example and it doesn't matter. Check last post update.

Comment: It will be working as a bad example in a computer memory but you can't save it to DB